# Unable to save form data to sql table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to save a form data into sql table using php. Eventhough I am not getting error while submit, data is not showing up in table.

My submit button name is `input_submit`
Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['input_submit'])){

include 'dbConnection.php';
include 'saveData.php'; 

}
```

dbConnection.php

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';


class ConnectDB{

    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;


    protected function connect(){

        $this->servername ="localhost";
        $this->username ="root";
        $this->password ="";
        $this->dbname ="testdb";

        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);

            if($conn -> connect_error) {

                die("connection failed:".$conn-> connect_error);
            }

        return $conn;

        }
}

?>
```

saveData.php:

```
<?php

    class saveinput extends ConnectDB {

    public function Savein(){

$date       = $_POST['date'];   
$entry_type = $_POST['entry_type'];
$amount     = $_POST['amount'];

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_myexpenses (date, entry_type, amount) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

$sql->bind_param("sss",$date, $entry_type, $amount);

$sql->execute();

if ($sql->execute()) { 
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "failed";
}


    }

}


?>
```

while submit, form is getting submitted. But when I check the db table, nothing is showing up. I am not understanding whats wrong here. Can someone guide me please.

Comment: Do you ever call these methods?

Comment: @Barmar:no.this is the first time I am using it

Comment: You're just defining the functions, you need to call them to execute the code.

Comment: @Barmar:thanks for the details. I added function connect() along with the execute like $sql->connect()->execute(); Is this the correct method ?. sorry I am new to php

Comment: Try to set pdo error reporting to exception so that you can see if there are any errors:$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: @Eva The code uses `mysqli`, not `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your "connect" method inside your Savein method in a var. So, your Savein method should be:

```
public function Savein(){
$conn = parent::connect(); // This is the only thing i've added

$date       = $_POST['date'];   
$entry_type = $_POST['entry_type'];
$amount     = $_POST['amount'];

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_myexpenses (date, entry_type, amount) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

$sql->bind_param("sss",$date, $entry_type, $amount);

if ($sql->execute()) { 
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "failed";
}


}
```

Comment: No luck with this

Comment: Still didnt work? Anyway, you should call `$sql->execute()` only once, in the if condition, otherwise, your data will be inserted twice. I've just edited it in my answer.